# jQuery scroll an element to the bottom

Tags: jquery, scroll

All I can find on the web tells me how to scroll the page to the bottom or to an element.

How is it possible to scroll a specific div which has the style "overflow:auto" to the bottom using jQuery?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes:

```
$("#container").scrollTop($("#elementToScrollTo").position().top);​
```

If you want to go smoothly:

```
$("#container").animate({
    scrollTop: $("#elementToScrollTo").position().top
}, 1000);
```

Here, have a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/adrianonantua/nxHE8/

Answer (score 10):

**JavaScript example**

```js
const elBox = document.querySelector("#box");
elBox.scrollTo({ top: elBox.scrollHeight, behavior: "smooth" });
```

**jQuery example**

```js
const $box = $("#box");
$box.animate({ scrollTop: $box.prop("scrollHeight"}, 700);
```

- [Element.scrollTo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo) Method.

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll the top, subtract the window height and add the element height. Your scroll should arrive right at the bottom of the element:

```
$( 'body' ).animate( {
    scrollTop: $( '#element' + currentElementId ).offset().top 
    + $( '#element' + currentElementId ).height() 
    - $( window ).height()
}, 1000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Element.scrollIntoView() with a 'false' argument worked perfectly for me.

```
const julie = document.getElementById('julie');

julie.scrollIntoView(); // default to 'true' argument, align top
julie.scrollIntoView(true) // align top
julie.scrollIntoView(false) // align bottom
```

https://hidde.blog/scroll-an-element-into-the-center-of-the-viewport/#heading-1