# Text overflows on a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div right now that when the text overflows, it makes it scroll. My questions are, Is there a way to make the scroll bars hidden until the text overflows? And is there a way to make it overflows only up and down, and not to the left and right?

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div>HelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHello</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! Use `overflow: auto;` and `word-break: break-all;`.

```
div {
    ...
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/631msL3L/2/

Note: `word-break` is not supported by Opera.

Comment: Updated. Issue is with how lines with no whitespace are broken (or not) by the browser.

Comment: Is there a way to make it automatically scrolled to bottom?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406250/jquery-scroll-an-element-to-the-bottom

Comment: @frosty "Is there a way to make the scroll bars hidden until the text overflows?" Your scroll bar is not hidden http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/631msL3L/1/

Comment: Yes, it is, if the text does not overflow.

Answer (score -2):

```
div {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```